# Azure VM MRD Login from Mac OSX fails for Azure Active Directory accounts

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, mac, entra-id

I have a VM in Azure with Windows (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter) on it.

We are all using Mac OSX laptops with Microsoft Remote Desktop on it.
I need this system because Power Bi Desktop doesn't exist for Mac.

At creation of the VM, I activated the option "Login with AAD credentials (Preview)".

I also added some accounts to the role assignments as described here : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/azure-ad-authentication-to-windows-vms-in-azure-now-in-public/ba-p/827840

But still I'm unable to login from my regular O365 user account into this server.
I have a local admin account for this server and I can connect with MRD without problems.
But I want to allow people in my organisation to use this server with their O365 credentials.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I did find a Windows 10 Home laptop. Also there I cannot login with my O365 credentials. So I must still doing something wrong in above procedure.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is adding "Azuread" in front of my emailaddress...
Unsure if I missed that in the documentation.
Anyway with this little change it works fine.